# Does the history of our concept of reality, tell us something about Reality?

Tags: ontology, reality

Whether looking at a human maturing or the progress of civilization, the idea about what Reality *is*, keeps on changing. And mostly it changes toward the more complex, more elusive, more difficult to understand. The phenomenon is well known and has been expressed by children and philosophers alike, eg. "There are more questions than answers". George Musser expresses it thus:

> The deeper that physicists dive, the more the concept of reality keeps
>   swimming away from them. -
>   https://blogs.scientificamerican.com/observations/is-reality-digital-or-analog-read-the-essays-and-cast-your-vote/

One may be tempted to suppose that this very *receding nature of ultimate answers* is an *ultimate feature* of Reality, a phenomenon worthy of investigation even.

**Question: Does the phenomenon itself tell us something about Reality? Is there any literature that explores this?**

Comment: You can see [Challenges to Metaphysical Realism](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/realism-sem-challenge/).

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Thanks. I didn't actually make that connection in terms of the bigger debate. I was thinking of the "phenomenon" as something that a realist  and non-realist would regard in the same terms. However their explanations would surely diverge greatly?

Comment: How do we know it doesn't just tell us something about physicists?

Comment: Where you are going with this is called [pessimistic meta-induction](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/scientific-realism/#PessIndu):"*the history of science furnishes vast evidence of empirically successful theories that were later rejected; from subsequent perspectives, their unobservable terms were judged not to refer and thus, they cannot not be regarded as true or even approximately true.*" This is one of the chief arguments against scientific (or any) realism, and yes, there is vast literature on it.

Comment: Until very recently, bacteria didn't exist... true story. They just popped into existance when Leeuwenhoek peered into his microscope. They'll.disappear again I suppose.

Comment: Reality is related to truth. Latin realis means *actual*. Reality means actually existing, or *true*. So like truth, there is absolute Reality and then the relative reality which is all that we currently know and experience either collectively or individually. There shouldn't be any problem with the *concept* of reality. Only that every subsequent discovery naturally engenders more and more questions along with the painful awareness of so many things about which we will always remain uncertain.

Comment: @Bread "more and more questions" not less and less: it is this _trend_ under question. Eg. what would it mean if we suddenly realize the the questions are now becoming less and less? - Assuming you know about the whole "it from bit" thing, what would the "it" look like if the "bits" encoded an untruth? Also see: https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/q/59490/33787

Comment: A more specific perspective on this are the two competing programs in modern physics, the platonistic "theory of everything" (currently, string theory), that aims at capturing Reality behind the curtain, vs the hierarchy of effective theories, like the Standard Model, with layered ontologies that get dissolved at the next level, do not "converge", and never end. A good discussion is [The Conceptual Foundations and the Philosophical Aspects of Renormalization Theory by Cao-Schweber, esp. pp.69-77](https://www.jstor.org/stable/20117830). But the clash seems to be what they call perennial.

Comment: @Conifold But this "phenomenon" holds in both programs? - If there are two, there will be more... Does humanity face a future scourged by warring clans of physicists?

Comment: @Richard What is interesting about that view is how well it gels with the Simulation hypothesis. I.e. only what is observed, is rendered...

Comment: @christo183 yes. Any tool which examines things beypnd the reach of our senses.

Comment: It might tell us something that while the development you mention has been going on in some quarters the perennial view of Reality has not altered by a jot in three millenna, and it never was complicated. I feel the history you refer to tells us a lot about Reality or at least indicates where the truth lies.

Comment: No. What makes it perennial is that in practice the two philosophies are complementary, and in different contexts at different times one or the other is more fruitful. As for possibility of multiple incompatible options that is unlikely for pragmatic reasons, once a good enough version is discovered people congregate to elaborate that one, so development of a full-blown alternative is deprived of the needed vast resources.

Comment: @Conifold This "complementary" aspect is a can of worms I'm still struggling to pick through. (in fact many of my questions are skirting the issue) I'll bet Pragmatism is just one of those worms... Tongue in cheek aside, I get the sense you see resources as the only obstacle to a proliferation of scientific paradigms?

Comment: There might be other obstacles, but this is a big one. But remember that these paradigms would have to cover the same empirical domain and produce comparable results. It is likely that, together with pragmatic benefits, this selects just one as having an edge, or they give multiple ways of making the same, or very close, predictions, with comparable costs, which can be quite useful rather than a burden, by giving different perspectives. Various interpretations of QM illustrate the idea.

Comment: https://physicsworld.com/a/quantum-physics-says-goodbye-to-reality/ The title says a great deal

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90742/discussion-on-question-by-christo183-does-the-history-of-our-concept-of-reality).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, currently it has been stated that reality can’t be described using the scientific method, at least good food for thought.

Read the following paper:
“Experimental rejection of observer-independence in the quantum world” https://arxiv.org/pdf/1902.05080.pdf

Answer (score 1):

You would have to know what Reality is, independently of our historical concepts of it, to know whether those concepts acquaint us in any way with its nature. But we only have the concepts, verifying which against Reality appears impossible : it would need access to an unconceptualised Reality to ascertain any difference or agreement between our concepts and Reality.

On the other hand, assuming that any concept of Reality itself is real, i.e. a genuine and existent mental phenomenon, we might reasonably claim to know that Reality is such as to admit conceptualisation - accurate or imperfect - of itself.

Comment: Now I'm thinking there are two possibilities: the "phenomenon" _is_ a feature of Reality or, it tells us something about how we are going about conceptualizing Reality. - OR, does anybody get the idea that Answers are like carrots to an ass.

Answer (score 1):

**This is a very old and influential concept in the world of philosophy**.  In the west, Plato conceived of ultimate Reality as something that our ordinary reality only imitated imperfectly.  In the east, Lao Tzu said the Dao that could be understood was not the true Dao.  *Ecclesiastes*, in the Bible, describes the fullest capacity of human wisdom as "worthless vanity."  More recently, Kant described the features of the universe that could never be grasped as its "noumenal" traits.

In contrast, the world of modern science has a history of confidence that the entirety of the important mysteries of existence would eventually come under its sphere of understanding.  **That confidence has begun to evaporate in the face of the new mysteries of quantum mechanics**.

*If this topic is of interest to you, I have an essay on it, [here](https://partiallyexaminedlife.com/2015/05/12/plato-and-the-god-of-the-gaps/).*

Comment: Not too fond of the gaps argument myself but: 1. the baffling, and well-known arrogance of humanity; who would say the gaps are small, even when those gaps have grown so much larger since first a scientist said there is nothing left to discover. 2. But suppose we could fill the gaps, and suppose God would so choose, then the tiniest crack in our knowledge would be a "divine domicile".

Answer (score 0):

> And mostly it changes toward the more complex, more elusive, more
>   difficult to understand.

From this statement I believe your question is about the Ultimate Reality.  If it is so,  it will always be like this (as mentioned above).    The main fault regarding your search is that you are trying to catch it with the organs that becomes formless or unreal (as per your above statement) after a certain period.  If so how could you understand it?  You should seek it within yourself.

> Question: Does the phenomenon itself tell us something about Reality?

Of course, it (the present experience you mentioned i.e., the complexity, elusiveness, difficulty to understand etc.,) shows that our sense organs can never catch it.  Since it cannot be controlled by mind or sense organs, understanding of the Ultimate Reality must be something more than understanding or experiencing. That is why it 'seems' to be complex, elusive and difficult to understand.

> Is there any literature that explores this?

Advaita vedanta has already named that ultimate reality 'Brahman'. And this word is usually used synonymous to God. [He who realizes the Ultimate Reality won't see a second thing; even an external God]  If we say 'Reality is Nothingness (or Nothingness is reality)', it certainly implies that it is no use seeking it. Advaita vedanta doesn't take you to that route.  If Nothingness were the Ultimate Reality, Kathopanishad wouldn't have exhorted to [awake to reach the goal.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arise,_awake,_and_stop_not_till_the_goal_is_reached)

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brahman

https://www.speakingtree.in/blog/brahman-is-the-ultimate-reality

Comment: Have not those who seek in themselves met with the same phenomenon? Perhaps the realization that answers are always receding, is a milestone in itself? Is there any particular mention in the Vedas of the "phenomenon"?

Comment: @christo183 - For the advaitan answers are not always receding but are regularly being reached. I would question the idea that 'Brahman' is properly used as a synonym for 'God' - otherwise the word 'Brahman' would be redundant - but either way this would be Ultimate and Real. This Ultimate is discussed at length in the Vedas and elsewhere. .

Comment: @PeterJ To clarify what I mean by "answers receding": When an answer is obtained, it creates many more new questions. That means that the ultimate/complete answer seems to recede, since our fraction of knowledge seems to diminish with each fractional answer... Just between us, I'm wondering if, should we be able to affect Reality, then this phenomenon may indicate that we are actually complicating Reality by looking at it in the wrong way. - 'Brahma' would be redundant?

Comment: @christo183 - I'd say the idea we're complicating Reality by looking at in the wrong way is spot on, We're only looking at one aspect of Plotinus' 'Simplex'.

Comment: @PeterJ almost like trying to record a _zero - many_ dimensional "WSOGMM" by means of a _three - four_ dimensional "observer"...

Comment: @christo183: "When an answer is obtained, it creates many more new questions."  ~  If the answer is correct/ultimate, there won't be a second thing to ask our question. "That means that the ultimate/complete answer seems to recede,...."  ~ He will understand whether it is ultimate or complete.

Comment: "....should we be able to affect Reality,...." ~  When one realizes that reality, he gets nothing that can be treated as 'physical'. If so, how should he able to affect Reality, and who should it do with his physical body?

Comment: "....then this phenomenon may indicate that we are actually complicating Reality by looking at it in the wrong way. - 'Brahma' would be redundant?"  ~ No problem, you may say that 'Brahma' is redundant.  But there must be another thing (that has consciousness) in its place in some other name.

Comment: Thanks, I think I get it now. Brahman is the idea I expressed as "zero - many dimensional "WSOGMM""? Brahma, (I was asking PeterJ about a typo) is the self- or  un-created, first consciousness? Anyway, the point that prompted my question is: Our _method_ of questioning should be in question itself. (especially in the "western tradition" where partial/incomplete answers are the norm)

Comment: @christo183: I believe the word in your comment--'Brahma' (instead of Brahman) was a typo. The two words are different.  Since there is nothing called time, you may say 'time' is just an idea. Brahman is not like that.

Comment: I didn't like the usage 'many dimensional' because ( I feel ) the word 'many' indicates something countable. When he realizes it he realizes that this verse (https://www.holy-bhagavad-gita.org/chapter/2/verse/20) is about the ultimate Reality (though the verse is about soul). He realizes that there is nothing to lose or gain.  http://www.rkmdelhi.org/articles/brahmans-nature-remains-unaltered/